# Convoluted Derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-analysis, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I'm trying to compute the first two derivatives of the map
$$
\Psi:X\mapsto (X^TX + f(X))^{-1}X^Ty,
$$
should be; where $y$ is a fixed vector and $X$ is a vector also.  Wehere, here $f(X)$ is a matrix-valued twice continuously differentiable function.  But I'm not very experienced in matrix calculus.

Comment: It is unclear. The derivatives with matrices inverses can be computed from $(I+h A)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-h)^k A^k$ for $h$ small enough

Comment: Did you mean $f$ is *matrix*-valued?

Comment: Yes I did; thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @ CSA , what do you write ? If $X $ is a vector (a column), then $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @loupblanc X is a row vector so X^TX is a matrix... if you prefer the dual expression:
X^T(XX^T +f(X))y you can use that too (in that case obv. X is a column vector)

Comment: And $y$ is another row vector, so $\Psi$ is also matrix-valued? Its first two derivatives are a rank-3 and a rank-4 tensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my solution in
[Matrix Derivative of Tichonov Regularization Operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2328571/matrix-derivative-of-tichonov-regularization-operator/2329206?noredirect=1#comment4812123_2329206)

Let $f_{ij}' = \partial f/\partial X_{ij}$ and $f_{ij,k\ell}'' = \partial^2 f/\partial X_{ij}\partial X_{k\ell}$. Then
$$
\phi_{ij} := \frac{\partial(X^T X+f(X))^{-1}}{\partial X_{ij}} = -(X^T X+f(X))^{-1}(X^T J^{ij} + J^{ji}X + f''_{ij})(X^T X+f(X)).
$$
and
$$
\psi_{ij} := \frac{\partial(X^T X+f(x))^{-1}X^T y}{\partial X_{ij}} = \phi_{ij}^TX^T y + (X^T X+f(x))^{-1}(y_j\cdot e_i).
$$

The second-order derivative can be similarly computed using chain rule:
$$
\frac{\partial^2(X^T X+f(x))^{-1}}{\partial X_{ij}\partial X_{k\ell}} = -\phi_{k\ell}^T\left[(X^T J^{ij}+J^{ji}X+f_{ij}')(X^TX+f(X))^{-1}X^T y-(y_i\cdot e_j)\right]\\
-(X^T X+f(X))^{-1}\left[(J^{\ell k}J^{ij}+J^{ji}J^{k\ell} + f_{ij,k\ell}'')(X^T X+f(X))^{-1}X^T y+(X^T J^{ij}+J^{ji}X+f_{ij}')\psi_{k\ell}\right].
$$

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks so much Yining!